Attempt to read a property on null?
Hi I am working on a laravel project and I am storing orders on my db and some of my values are not being sotred and showing NULL on the database this is my orders table
This is how I am storing data into database via a Controller:
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $order = new Order;
        //$order->product_name = request('product_name');
        $order->prenom = request('prenom');
        $order->nom = request('nom');
        $order->nom_entreprise = request('nom_entreprise');
        $order->commune_id   = request('commune_id  ');
        $order->product_id = request('product_id');
        $order->telephone = request('telephone');
        $order->email = request('email');
        $order->wilaya_id  = request('wilaya_id ');
        $order->subtotal = request('subtotal');
        $order->tax = request('tax');
        $order->status = request('status');
        $order->qty = request('qty');
        $order->total = request('total');

        $order->save();
    }

And this is the Migration code :
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('commune_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('wilaya_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('nom_nom_entreprise')->nullable();
            $table->integer('telephone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('livraison')->nullable();
            $table->double('subtotal');
            $table->double('tax')->nullable();
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->double('total');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Note
when I dd($request->commune_id ,$request->wilaya_id); it retrive both their Id's just fine but when storing on the databse the values are NULL 
here is the model code :
Order Model
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['nom' ,'wilaya_id', 'commune_id'];
    public function produits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Produit::class);
    }

    public function wilaya()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Wilaya::class, 'wilaya_id');
    }

    public function commune()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Commune::class, 'commune_id');
    }
    public function setFilenamesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['filenames'] = json_encode($value);
        //$this->attributes['properties'] = json_encode($value);
    }
}

Wilaya Model
class Wilaya extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['nom'];
    use HasFactory;
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
    public function communes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Commune::class);
    }
}

Commune Model
class Commune extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'wilaya_id'];
    use HasFactory;

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function wilaya()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Wilaya::class);
    }
}

Please Feel free to tell me what I could have done to solve this.
Thanks
